# Angular ng-switch with conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, conditional-statements, ng-switch

I have `ng-switch="field.type"` for an element containing `ng-switch-when` but I'd like to have the switch on when it's more than just one `field.type`.

I would assume something like `ng-switch-when="type1 || type2"` would work, but it doesn't.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: like this: `ng-switch-when="{{typ1 || type2}}"`

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal that didn't work at all

Comment: type1 and type2 should be in $scope then...

Comment: They are in the $scope, they work on their own too

Answer (score 0):

You can do solve it by copying the same ng-switch-when element (ie. element with the same content/innerHTML) for every value.

Like this:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div ng-switch="expression">
      <div ng-switch-when="matchvalue1">Item 1</div>
      <div ng-switch-when="matchvalue2">Item 1</div>
      <div ng-switch-when="matchvalue3">Item 3</div>
      <div ng-switch-default>default</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JoeSham/HB7LU/9201/

Comment: Right, but with more code that seems quite inefficient and wrong.

Comment: Well this is actually the solution from angularjs docs. I think it is efficient enough, maybe not quite so elegant. If you want an elegant solution, you can create your own ng-switch-directive.